# Mac Dark Mode Copies White Text

Tags: macos, colors, copy-paste, text-formatting

I am using dark mode on my mac and have an annoying problem of when I try to copy and paste text the pasted text is white. Is there a way to auto choose the right text color when pasting?

Example Usage: I copy text from the note app and then paste into Skype for Business. Skype for Business does not have dark mode and thus sends white text that no one can read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have at least some text in the target window, yes.

Once the text is copied you can go to the edit menu and select "Paste and match style" or tap <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>. Which is the keyboard shortcut for that menu item (as illustrated in the menu next to the option).

Simple! ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately this does remove rich text stuff like tables.